# Creating oval animation with css

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

```css
body {
  background: darkblue
}

#planetone {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 460px;
  left: 45%;
  margin: -20px;
  font-size: 100px;
  animation: myOrbit 10s infinite linear;
  color: white;
}

@keyframes myOrbit {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(5px) translateY(170px) rotate(0deg) scale(1);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(5px) translateY(170px) rotate(-90deg) scale(.75);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(5px) translateY(170px) rotate(-180deg) scale(.60);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(5px) translateY(270px) rotate(-270deg) scale(.75);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(5px) translateY(170px) rotate(-360deg) scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="planetone"><img width='100px' src="http://dots.com.ge/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/WEBArtboard-1.png" />
  <h6 style='color:white;margin-top:-55px;'>Social Media</h6>
</div>

<img style='display:inline-block;transform:translateY(-85px) !important;margin-top:150px;transform:scale(1.2)' src='http://dots.com.ge/dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/ასტყროlines.png'>
```

I need to animate object in oval path.

http://dots.com.ge/development/

On third section you can see little planet rotating around big one, I would like it to rotate exactly on the first orbit and then add 8 like that, I could not quite figure out exact anmation code.

Im using this animation code:

```
  @keyframes rotAroundOrbit {

       0%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(5px) translateY(170px) rotate(0deg) scale(1); }

       25% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(5px) translateY(170px) rotate(-90deg) scale(.75); }

       50%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(5px) translateY(170px) rotate(-180deg) scale(.60); }

       75%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(5px) translateY(270px) rotate(-270deg) scale(.75); }

       100%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(5px) translateY(170px) rotate(-360deg) scale(1); }

}
```

It's close but not going the way I would like it to.

Comment: please provide a snippet showing what happens now. in the editor press the snippet button.

Comment: got snippet in, I need the ball to rotate around the smallest orbit line, then I will add 8 like that with the same logic. it could also been seen on website that I provided

Comment: yea, but in 5 years that website might not exist anymore. Gotta thing about the future. looking at the thing now :-)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `I would like it to rotate exactly on the first orbit and then add 8 like that,` maybe include a drawing of what you see as the end result?